# What does $\omega^*$ mean?

Tags: set-theory, notation, ordinal-numbers

I've recently found in some short article (source below) the symbol $\omega^*$ (generally, starred ordinal number), but without explanation what that symbol means. From the context I understood that in some way it is $\omega$, but with reversed order, and the author uses it as if it were ordinal (I specifically mean arithmetic $\omega^* + \omega$)... but is it at all isomorphic to some well-ordered set? It seems confusing. I will be grateful for help in understanding the symbol $\omega^*$ and the sum $\omega^* + \omega$.

Source: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm7/cm7110.pdf

Comment: It is indeed just $\omega$ with the order reversed. It is not well-ordered, since it has an infinite descending chain. (It *is* an infinite descending chain.) It looks like the author extends addition of ordinals to addition of arbitrary order types in the natural way, so every element of first summand will be $\leq$ every element of second summand.  $\omega^* + \omega$ would then be the order-type of the integers. The author also mentions the order types "less than" $\omega^* + \omega$; I'd guess this means orders that can be embedded into $\omega^* + \omega$.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, now it makes a sense.

Comment: Orders can be added and multiplied. We mostly do it with ordinals, since they are closed under these operations in a very strong sense (namely, if $\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_i$ is well-ordered, then $I$ and each $\alpha_i$ are all ordinals; assuming that $\alpha_i\neq 0$ for all $i\in I$). But you can just as well define order arithmetic, and it's a useful concept, too.

Comment: To follow up on @Asaf Karagila's comment, the arithmetic of order types is often found in older set theory texts. See [**Theory of Sets**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486601412) by Kamke (1950), [**Abstract Set Theory**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Abstract+Set+Theory%22+Fraenkel) by Fraenkel (1953, 1961, 1966), [**Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cardinal+and+ordinal+numbers%22+sierpinski) by Sierpinski (1957, 1965). And especially see [**Linear Orderings**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Linear+Orderings%22+Rosenstein) by Rosenstein (1982).